# Not able to write the CSV File in a Flask app

Tags: python, pandas, csv, flask

I have created this simple application on flask where a user can upload a csv file containing names and it will return a new csv file which will be having only those names which starts with S or M. 
When I click on upload it should download the new file but I don't know where I am getting wrong. Probably in writing down the csv. Please help me out.
Using Python 3.x
Here is the app.py

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import csv
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template, send_from_directory
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/uploads/'
DOWNLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/downloads/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'csv'}

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/static")
DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['DOWNLOAD_FOLDER'] = DOWNLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 8 * 1024 * 1024


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            print('No file attached in request')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            print('No file selected')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            process_file(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename), filename)
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))
    return render_template('index.html')


def process_file(path, filename):
    update_file(path, filename)

def update_file(path, filename):
    data= pd.read_csv(path)
    work = data['first'].tolist()

    work_final=[]

    for item in work:
        if(checkitems(item) == True):
            work_final.append(item)

    headers = {}
    headers[str('content-type')] ='text/csv'
    headers['Content_Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+filename +'.csv'
    f = open(path + filename + '.csv' , 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(work_final)
    f.close()

def checkitems(items):
    if (items[0] == 'S' or items[0] == 'M'):
        return True
    else:
        return False


@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['DOWNLOAD_FOLDER'], filename, as_attachment=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

and here is the template index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Name Changer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1> Avinash Name Filter</h1>
        <h2> Upload the CSV File here</h2>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <input type="submit" value=Upload>
        </form>     
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me out.

I have attached this sample csv here

```
seq,first,age,date
1,Bernice,36,08/22/2013
2,Dale,63,07/18/1964
3,Oscar,53,05/02/1943
4,Elijah,57,12/13/1919
5,Chad,48,04/26/1958
6,Mabel,22,01/22/1916
7,Clayton,29,01/06/1901
8,James,47,07/01/1944
9,Olga,65,02/09/2020
10,Helena,23,03/11/2045
11,Jessie,31,01/07/2032
12,Ann,58,10/20/2058
13,Sallie,32,12/05/2009
14,Brandon,34,07/16/2067
15,Millie,61,07/10/2051
16,Travis,25,12/07/1997
17,Charlie,39,01/08/2001
18,Lester,19,01/31/1922
19,Charles,59,05/01/1929
20,Dennis,27,06/28/2050
21,Sean,28,07/12/2013
22,Jeffrey,33,10/04/2001
23,Evelyn,26,06/27/2048
24,Nell,32,03/05/1981
25,Gavin,30,04/08/2031
26,Mitchell,20,03/12/1977
27,Ruby,37,07/01/2024
28,Wesley,30,06/27/2060
29,Wesley,31,01/30/1978
30,Mina,49,10/20/2056
31,Daisy,43,04/05/1998
32,Martin,59,02/24/1964
33,Lee,39,01/24/2015
34,Timothy,58,11/20/2028
35,Rosetta,42,08/11/2020
36,Darrell,51,11/11/1984
37,Bess,42,06/04/1956
38,Estelle,52,06/08/2042
39,Aaron,65,09/03/2021
40,Jon,50,11/15/2000
41,Cory,32,06/14/1901
42,Leroy,63,07/02/2003
43,Grace,19,11/24/1929
44,Dennis,63,07/31/1927
45,Christopher,24,11/21/1968
46,Nancy,24,03/05/1948
47,Edith,65,08/31/1961
48,Raymond,39,01/10/1948
49,Agnes,22,11/28/1921
50,Steve,47,04/09/2052
```

Here is the link to csv - https://a.uguu.se/DMHQAUYuqqFh_test.csv

Comment: Here is a great tutorial for writing flask apps. The answer you want is in here, but it will also give a huge amount of insight into the next steps, after you get your file upload working. It talks about long running background tasks, flask forms (class object forms), databases and their models with Flask sqlalchemy plus a bunch of other really useful information, like jinja2 template engine. Hope this helps.https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world